# Matching and Joining Two Inconsistent DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that are being queried off two separate databases that share common characteristics, but not always the same characteristics, and I need to find a way to reliably join the two together.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'Name':'Jose', 'Age':12,'Location':'Frankfurt','Occupation':'Student','Mothers Name':'Rosy'}, {'Name':'Katherine','Age':23,'Location':'Maui','Occupation':'Lawyer','Mothers Name':'Amy'}, {'Name':'Larry','Age':22,'Location':'Dallas','Occupation':'Nurse','Mothers Name':'Monica'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print (df)

   Age   Location Mothers Name       Name Occupation
0   12  Frankfurt         Rosy       Jose    Student
1   23       Maui          Amy  Katherine     Lawyer
2   22     Dallas       Monica      Larry      Nurse



inp2 = [{'Name': '','Occupation':'Nurse','Favorite Hobby':'Basketball','Mothers Name':'Monica'},{'Name':'Jose','Occupation':'','Favorite Hobby':'Sewing','Mothers Name':'Rosy'},{'Name':'Katherine','Occupation':'Lawyer','Favorite Hobby':'Reading','Mothers Name':''}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(inp2)
print(df2)

  Favorite Hobby Mothers Name       Name Occupation
0     Basketball       Monica                 Nurse
1         Sewing         Rosy       Jose           
2        Reading               Katherine     Lawyer
```

I need to figure out a way to reliably join these two dataframes without the data always being consistent. To further complexify the problem, the two databases are not always the same length. Any ideas?

Comment: so if you can join on any 2 of (mother's name, name, occupation), that's ok?

Comment: you'll need to provide more info - show what is the expected end result (an example given your input)

Answer (score 0):

you can preform your merge on your possible column combinations and concat those dfs then merge your new df on the first (complete) df:

```
# do your three possible merges on 'Mothers Name', 'Name', and 'Occupation'
# then concat your dataframes
new_df = pd.concat([df.merge(df2, on=['Mothers Name', 'Name']), 
                    df.merge(df2, on=['Name', 'Occupation']),
                    df.merge(df2, on=['Mothers Name', 'Occupation'])], sort=False)

# take the first dataframe, which is complete, and merge with your new_df and drop dups
df.merge(new_df[['Age', 'Location', 'Favorite Hobby']], on=['Age', 'Location']).drop_duplicates()

    Age Location    Mothers Name    Name      Occupation    Favorite Hobby
0   12  Frankfurt      Rosy         Jose       Student        Sewing
2   23  Maui           Amy          Katherine  Lawyer         Reading
4   22  Dallas         Monica       Larry      Nurse          Basketball
```

This assumes that each rows age and location are unique